# spotify trackset link doesn't work

Tags: embed, spotify, playlist

When you embed a spotify track list there is an option to copy the link. This link doesn't work. Does anyone know how to get it to work or why it's not working?

Here is an example of the player: http://static.echonest.com/playlist/SpotifyTrackList.html

On hover of player you have option to copy the link or the embed code. Here is the link I want to get working: http://open.spotify.com/trackset/abba_playlist/12TwKFjedaPfO6a5p9mo6D,6Zur808QieVQAdXbgwMzMN,1fQyiulxuPu8ywfIrOM3ft,2PTJh1Yt9Z2g4AifpJ8Gs0,6gFhejgj1XAP86XuA2DAG4,6HyYUvLLHlvBcAho2fgBvd,0AWpG6NUEaRZvS3eMvXkBg,56BSwBKWHYldQOgYLHiehs,4jfSPSlCyS1ywRbN4iod8D,6aOMyKSl8bnayyILufaaVa,2ZItUHJBx3kn3QupNexzS5,1lJ219Hvtp5kDe3RqGYqto

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is the solution:

```
<a href="spotify:trackset:Playlist:49MsPNQCOmxvIYi9AdoPzY,6fUlrsHaz4QfCNF31rk2dU,5KiTsR2h8jnzkvTeucxoAn,6kidUwWb8tB9ktfy7U76iX,6mlUEdb90RqwUisnp65lG7,6KOEK6SeCEZOQkLj5M1PxH,3psrcZoGRaWh6FMGael1NX,3EHLii6bnZxJxsCfLlIb83,0xJtHBdhpdLuClaSQYddI4,6fsdOFwa9lTG7WKL9sEWRU,">Play in Spotify</a>
```